# mvn release:prepare does not ignore file it is expected to ignore

Tags: maven, svn

I'm running

```
mvn release:prepare
```

which results in the following error. It complains a file was modified, which should have been ignored in the first place, since mvn put it there.

> [INFO] Change the default 'svn' provider implementation to 'javasvn'.

[...]

> [INFO]   ignoring changes on: **/pom.xml.backup, release.properties, **/release.properties, **/pom.xml.branch, **/pom.xml.next, **/pom.xml.releaseBackup, **/pom.xml.tag

[...]

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:prepare (default-cli) on project company-common: Cannot prepare the release because you have local modifications :
>
> [ERROR] [/home/ansible/branch/company-common/branches/1.0.2-JM/release.properties:unknown]

This is a commonly reported problem. Most answers suggest using relative paths for scm config. My question is how to do that? Relative to what? Here my scm for a branch:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://ipsvndev.company.com/repos/PROJ/company-common/branches/1.0.2-JM</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://ipsvndev,company.com/repos/PROJ/company-common/branches/1.0.2-JM</developerConnection>
    <url>scm:svn:http://ipsvndev.company.com/repos/PROJ/company-common/branches/1.0.2-JM</url>
</scm>
```

Comment: I have a work around <checkModificationExcludes>
           <checkModificationExclude>/**/release.properties</checkModificationExclude>
        </checkModificationExcludes>

Comment: I can either add this to my parent or my children - which is better? Parent I suppose.